# Functions Not Appearing in Debug / Run

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I am unable to see all but 2 of my custom functions in the function list for debug / run menu dropdown.

[image: google script screenshot]

Here is a screenshot. You can notice that there are 2 functions in the dropdown, while I have more than 10 other functions which are not appearing.

What could be the reason for this?

Appreciate your help

Comment: the underscore at the end of the name `_` means its a private function. Remove the underscore

Comment: That worked. Thanks!